# problems to draw in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas, ionic2

in the html file

```
<canvas #canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button (click)="draw()" ion-button block icon-right>Donate <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon></button>
```

in the ts file

```
import { Component , ViewChild , ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    @ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef; 

    info:any;
    ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

    ngViewAfterInit()
    {
      this.canvas.nativeElement.setAttribute("width", window.innerWidth.toString());
      this.canvas.nativeElement.setAttribute("height", window.innerWidth.toString());
      this.ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
    }

    draw()
    {
         console.log(this.ctx); //this line displays : "undefined"
         this.ctx.fillStyle = "#C00";
         this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    }

}
```

ctx is undefined - I don't know why ??

when calling this method draw()

it displays "undefined" then error -> cannot set property 'fillStyle' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such hook called - **`ngViewAfterInit()`**

The correct lifecycle hook is - **`ngAfterViewInit()`**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef;

  info: any;
  ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.canvas.nativeElement.setAttribute("width", window.innerWidth.toString());
    this.canvas.nativeElement.setAttribute("height", window.innerWidth.toString());
    this.ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
  }

  draw() {
    console.log(this.ctx);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "#C00";
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  }

}
```